# Can't export Model with IK Constraint

Tags: animation

I have some issue with Blender when I export my model with IK Constraint to .FBX file then open with 3D viewer it said:"Couldn't load 3D model". I've tried to import that file to Unity but model pose was wrong. If I remove IK contraint bone then everything get back to normal. Can anybody help me :(

Answer (score 1):

Constraints can't be exported.

IK must be built on the software it's being used in, in your case Unity.

Comment: That means I have to do the animation without the IK ? :(

Comment: It depends. If you animate in Blender, you can use whatever you want, just the deforming bones will be baked and exported. Though it requires you to have made your rig accordingly: with a separated layer of bones that only deforms the model, and another layer that controls to deforming bones and have all the constraints and tools you want. On export, you only export the deforming bones and let the exporter bake each frame of the animation, so that the game engine only receives the "result" of your animation.