# when I export the ik rig to an fbx I loose the ability to use the ik

Tags: rigging

when I export the ik rig to an fbx I loose the ability to use the ik when I import it back into blender, any ideas what am I doing wrong?

the ik rig parts get really big and im missing some when I export it(shown in 2nd image)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218046/cant-export-model-with-ik-constraint